# Is it possible to programmatically include specific layout with Kotlin Android Extension?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Let's say I have two layouts *`activity_home_1`* and *`activity_home_2`* for my `HomeActivity`. 
I want to be able to switch between them like I used to do in Java:

```
int layout = getResources().getIdentifier("activity_home_" + getHomeScreenNumber(),"layout",getPackageName());
setContentView(layout);
```

And later reference elements of my layout using `findViewById();`

Of course, all the elements in those two layouts are named the same, they are just different looking, so this is working perfectly in Java.

---

On the other side in Kotlin, I'm avoiding `findViewById()` and I'm using **Kotlin Android Extensions**, and it's working great with including one layout like this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home_1.*
```

The trouble is when I want to switch between them. Just simply adding another import for the other layout it's causing an error because it doesn't know which layout to look at (cause they both have the same fields).

How can I switch between two layouts when using **Kotlin Android Extensions**?

Comment: You should consider using fragments in this case. Anyhow you won't be able to achieve this in the Activity. If all views are the same by type, you wouldn't even need to. The synthetic properties don't verify your layout. Also you have to consider the caching of the views with the synthetic properties. So you'd have to disable caching or make sure the cache is cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple and I wasn't paying enough attention.
It was to include the desired layout with:

```
setContentView(..)
```

---

For example, if you include

- `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home_1.*`

and in your `OnCreate()` set the

- `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_3)`

Now, your *activity_home_3* layout will be shown and their elements will be referenced!

**No need for findViewById()**